# How to ignore blank value while selecting from database?

Tags: mysql

There are 5 columns in my details table,id,filename,.....etc.In filename column there are 6 rows and only 2 rows have values.

It looks like this,

[image]

But, In my select statement I want to select only filled values means when I use,

```
select filename from details where some conditions to ignore black filename filed;
```

when I use count also,it should give count only 2.

What conditions I have to use here?

Comment: select filename from details where filename is not null

Comment: "blank" (i.e. empty string - `''`) or `null`? Not the same thing, especially when dealing with varchars. Ideally, don't store blank strings, unless this is specifically listed as a valid value in the application's requirements. Don't use it to represent the _absence of a value_ - that is what `null` is for. It's not clear from your screenshot whether the fields are actually null, or simply contain empty strings. This is a good reason why screenshots are not that helpful, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following solution using [`TRIM`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) and [`IFNULL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull):

```
SELECT filename 
FROM details 
WHERE TRIM(IFNULL(filename, '')) <> ''
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `filename` column contains something (but not null), you can check it with `filename > ''`. So, I would suggest a simple condition like :

```
select filename from details where filename is not null and filename > ''
```